# add a column (dependent on values within the table)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm looking to add a column to a table and populate the column with values resulting from the same table. So, the where clause:

```
where column A = 1 and column b = 3 then 0
where column A = 2 and column b = 1 then 1.
```

I know its a lame queation but can someone point me in the right direction?

Also, the original table was created using a stored procedure as part of a process. Do I need to alter the process to add this column or do as above?

Comment: so what will be the value of the other column if it does not meet your condition above?

Comment: Maybe you show some code?

Comment: If it doesn't meet the conditions,  then 2.

Comment: Um, why do you have a stored proc to create a table?  Assuming you need to use the stored proc multiple times, and have it include this column, then of course you have to modify it.  It looks like SQL Server [supports some form of in-db derived columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069(v=sql.100).aspx).  Otherwise, you could presumably use a trigger to maintain these values.  Or, if the overhead is low enough, just create a view that derives it at `SELECT` time...

Comment: why would you need a new column that is totally functional dependent? you would be introducing a redundancy in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table T add column C integer

update T set C = case when A = 1 and B = 3 then 0
                      when A = 2 and B = 1 then 1
                      else 2 end
```

And neither I do understand why to use a stored procedure...